stable Load Balancer for Elasticsearch cluster without Kubernetes
I am looking for a solution for elasticsearch cluster Load balancer  not in Kubernetes.
In my architecture, I'll have a few master nodes that acts as a coordinator as well and a few data nodes that acts as coordinators as well.
I need to have a stable URL for high availability which will act as a Load Balancer.

what is the best solution for Load Balancer for the ES cluster for high availability and also better performance taking into consideration that it's without Kubernetes?

As I see it there are 2 options:

Some external Load balancer for the cluster - and only to this LB I ll approach from outside the cluster.

to use some Round Robin algorithm and every time to approach a different coordinator of the cluster.


What is the better way?
